# How can I increment last byte of 32bits key in python?

Tags: python

I am having difficulty figuring out how to increment the last byte of 32bits key.
For example value of key is 
key = b"3333"*8

Comment: Please provide an example input and the expected output.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Could you include what `b"3333"*8` represents? Is that hex-notation or decimal? And what would be the expected output?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `key[:-1] + bytes([key[-1] + 1])`? Maybe you should use a `bytearray`, which is mutable, rather than `bytes` objects, which are immutable

Comment: @MSeifert I'm just trying to understand what the question is asking. I'm not sure what you mean about hex vs decimal, it makes no difference as far as I can tell.

Comment: So, seriously, you should be using a `bytearray` in which case this becomes trivial: `b_arr = bytearray(b'3333'); b_arr[-1] += 1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may help

```
def inc(v):
    nope = lambda x: x
    def increment(vv):
        tmp = vv
        if increment.i == 1:
            tmp = 1+increment.to_int(vv)
            increment.i = tmp / 256
            tmp = increment.to_char(tmp%256)
        return tmp
    increment.to_char = chr if (type(v) == str) else nope
    increment.to_int = ord if (type(v) == str) else nope
    increment.i = 1
    return map(increment, v[::-1])[::-1]
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an answer to a different question? It has nothing to do with the one asked here.

Comment: Well, it actually does. Just try it ;)

Comment: This returns a list of `int` objects in Python 2, and in Python 3, it fails.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, you are right. It was coded in Python 2 and also, it returns list of int objects. You will need to cast it back to bytearray. However, thanks for pointing out Python 3 issue.

Comment: As an aside, it is *extremely* convoluted, relying on a nested function (why dont you define `increment` outside `inc`?) and relies on function attributes... not exactly clean

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, just related to your last response to the question, it does not solve the borrowed byte, does it?